# What is the correct way of defining the class constructor?

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to multiply two matrices by passing to the class which will do multiplication. I am facing the problem while defining the constructor please help me with this..(errror is shown below)

My header file is MatMul.h as :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class MatMul
{
    double **C;
    int row,col,common;
public:

    MatMul(int p,int q,int r)
    {
        row=p; col=q,common=r;
        C=new double *[row];
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
            C[row]=new double [col];
    }

    void multiply(double A[][3],double B[][3],int p,int q,int r)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<row;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<col;j++)
            {
                C[i][j]=0;
                for(int k=0;k<r;k++)
                {
                    C[i][j]=C[i][j]+A[i][k]*B[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

and the maincpp file is

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include"MatMul.h"

int main()
{
    int p=3,q=3,r=3;
    double A[p][r]={{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}};
    double B[r][q]={{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}};
    MatMul c(p,q,r);
    c.multiply(A,B,p,q,r);

    return 0;
}
```

It is showing

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘MatMul::multiply(double [p][r], double [r][q], int&, int&, int&)’
```

Please can you identify the error and update it.

Comment: `double A[p][r]` is non standard if `q` and `r` are not constants. Try using `const int p=3, q=3`

Comment: There is no sense in `double A[p][r]={{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}}`. The init values are fixed (3x3) and `p`,`r` are "variables". Simply put `double A[3][3]`.

Answer (score 0):

Static array size cannot come from a non-const variable.

This will compile fine (made `p`, `q` and `r` `const`):

```
const int p=3,q=3,r=3;
double A[p][r]={{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}};
double B[r][q]={{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}};
```

Also, no need to include `<iostream>` twice (not even once as you d'ont use it). `using namespace std;` is also useless in your code.